# Remove Payment Method from WooCommerce Completed Order Email

Tags: email, woocommerce, customization

I'm wondering how to remove just the payment method from the WooCommerce Completed Order notification email (but NOT the Order Processing email).  Any ideas?

Tried this within the email template:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'adjust_woocommerce_get_order_item_totals' );

function adjust_woocommerce_get_order_item_totals( $totals ) {
  unset($totals['cart_subtotal']  );
  unset( $totals['payment_method'] );
  return $totals;
}
 ?>
```

Nothing happened

Here is my existing email template without mods:

```
<?php
/**
 * Customer completed order email
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/customer-completed-order.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates\Emails
 * @version 3.7.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_header() Output the email header
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>

<?php /* translators: %s: Customer first name */ ?>
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Hi %s,', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $order->get_billing_first_name() ) ); ?></p>
<p><?php esc_html_e( 'We have finished processing your order.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
<?php

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_details() Shows the order details table.
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_order_data() Generates structured data.
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::output_structured_data() Outputs structured data.
 * @since 2.5.0
 */

 add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'adjust_woocommerce_get_order_item_totals' );

do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_meta() Shows order meta data.
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::customer_details() Shows customer details
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_address() Shows email address
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/**
 * Show user-defined additional content - this is set in each email's settings.
 */
if ( $additional_content ) {
    echo wp_kses_post( wpautop( wptexturize( $additional_content ) ) );
}

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_footer() Output the email footer
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', $email );
```

Can I just add something to this code to remove ONLY the payment method?

Comment: Just copy the email template into your theme and comment the details you dont want to send. The template is located in woocommerce -> templates -> emails -> customer-complate-order.php or Login to your website and go to  WooCommerce settings. Click on the "Emails" tab. Find the "Completed Order" email and click on the "Manage" button. Scroll down to the email template section and click on the "Copy files to theme" button. This will copy the email template files to your theme folder.

Comment: This doesn't work because ALL of the order details are contained within this line: /* do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ); */ so when I comment them out I lose everything else too - I need a way to separate out just the shipping method info.  I've found ways to do this in the functions.php file but then it applies to ALL Woo emails and I only want it to apply to the Completed Order email...